# Exercise 2.17 in Miles Reid's Commutative Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

In exercise 2.17 in Reid's book I need to prove the third isomorphism theorem for modules:

> If $L \subseteq M \subseteq N$ are modules, then $N/M \cong (N/L)/(M/L)$

using Snake lemma, but I don't see how I can apply it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $p$, $q$, $r$ are the three *vertical* morphisms, the *Snake lemma* gives a long exact sequence:$\DeclareMathOperator\coker{coker}$
$$0\to\ker p\to \ker q\to\ker r \xrightarrow{\partial} \coker p\to\coker q\to\coker r\to 0.$$
From the diagram you have, you deduce $\ker r=0$, and as $q$  is surjective, and the diagram is commutative, $r$ is surjective too. Whence $r$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand this. In the beginning we have two s.e.s.: $0 \to M \to N \to N/M \to 0$ and $0 \to M/L \to N/L \to (N/L)/(M/L) \to 0$. $p, q$ are quotient homomorphisms, but what is $r$? We need to find it first, so that the diagram is actually commutative, right?   But then the isomorphism theorem would be obvious (you just see $\ker$ and $\text{im}$ of $r$). How the snake lemma helps in this question? Does it give the opportunity to skip the part with construction of $r$?

Comment: The snake lemma only helps proving $r$ is injective. As to the construction of $r$, do you know the universal property of cokernels?

Comment: No, but I think I know how to construct $r$. We just pull back an element in $N/L$ to $N$ and then map it to $N/M$. It is well-def. since $L \subseteq M$. In my opinion, proving that this diagram commutes is a much harder task than proving the third isomorphism theorem as usual.

Comment: Yes, just some diagram-chasing. It will be a little longer, but not that longer, and it will be more explicit. In any way, you should need to use the fact that the composed map $M\to N\to N/L\to \operatorname{coker}$ is the $0$ map.